# How to replay the video without buffer in angular ngx-videogular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using the package @videogular/ngx-videogular. it is working fine with buffer when play first time but buffers again on replay. it should not buffer on replay and should play already loaded video. is it possible with ngx-videogular library

```
<vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
     <video [vgMedia]="$any(media)" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" crossorigin>
      <source src="http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
</vg-player>
```